# Flutter and Firebase: Why is data not returned sorted by id?

Tags: flutter, dart, sorting, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to return data from firestore database sorted by id. After updating one entry data is returned with one record out of sort. After updating a second entry to confirm issue data is again returned now with two records out of sort. Id is a number on the db and so should be in numeric order.

Here is the code:

```
  Future getKegIds() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("kegs").orderBy("id", descending: false ).get().then(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach(
            (document) {
                  print(document.reference);
                  kegIds.add(document.reference.id);
            },
          ),
    );
  }
```

and here are the results:

- flutter: (kegs/keg:1)
- flutter: (kegs/keg:2)
- flutter: (kegs/keg:3)
- flutter: (kegs/keg:4)
- flutter: (kegs/keg:5)
- flutter: (kegs/keg:6)
- flutter: (kegs/keg:7)
- flutter: (kegs/keg:8)
- flutter: (kegs/keg:9)
- flutter: (kegs/keg:10)
- flutter: (kegs/keg:11)
- flutter: (kegs/keg:15)
- flutter: (kegs/keg:16)
- flutter: (kegs/keg:12)
- flutter: (kegs/keg:13)

Kegs 15 and 16 are out of order.

Comment: Is keg:1 mean a field call keg with a value 1?

Comment: It means keg 1.  The record represents a keg and the '1' is the id of the record or keg.

Comment: So where you see 'orderBy("id", descending: false)' in the code, the numbers represent the ids.

Answer (score 0):

I think is something like `orderBy(FieldPath.documentId)`, `orderBy('id')` is order by a field in document call `id`.

Comment: I want order the documents by the field called 'id'.  however the results are not sorted correctly whenever I update a field in a document.